# How to save a specific value from a http request

Tags: c#, http, request, httprequest

First off, I´m a beginner regarding C#. To the question.. When executing this code it returns me some values in form of strings and numbers, for example:"Hello World, my name is Jon, from planet 10230120" How can I then choose what I want to save to a Query? Lets say I only want to save "10230120" to a query

Code I have so far:

```
    GetRequest("mylink");

    Console.ReadKey();

    }

    async static void GetRequest(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync(url))

            {
              using(HttpContent content = respons.Content)
                {
                    string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
```

Comment: You could use regular expressions to get the number(s) that you need.

Comment: Typically responses are more structured than what you are showing as the response text ... usually whoever published the specific URL would provide some sort of schema for the response and you could use serialization/deserialization to get the values from an object rather than trying to parse a string.